# Вывод input name AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Нужно вывести в тег заполненное имя
форма:

```
        <form class="job-form header__call-form" id="dataler" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="checked_form" value="Заказ обратного звонка">
            <div class="title">
                <p>Заказ обратного звонка</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
                    <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder=" " required name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
                    <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder=" " required name="phone">
                </div>
                <div class="input-wrap">
                    <fieldset class="header__call-quest">
                        <legend>Когда вам перезвонить?</legend>
                        <label>
                            <input id="timeChoice1" type="radio" name="worktime[]" checked value="Сейчас"><span>Сейчас</span>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="timeChoice2" type="radio" name="worktime[]" value="Вечером"><span>Вечером</span>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="timeChoice3" type="radio" name="worktime[]" value="Указать точное время"><span>Указать точное время</span>
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="note">
                    <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p><a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Заказать</span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Ajax

```
  $("form#dataler").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'sendler.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: formData,
      success: function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.header__call-form').hide();
        $('.header__call-form--success').show();
        $('.header__call-form--success > .name').text(data.name);
      },
      error: function error(data) {
        console.log('error');
        // после отправки формы в консоле выводится массив с получеными данными
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });
```

и сам блок с обращением по имени при успешной отправке

```
<div class="header__call-form--success">
                    <p class="name">Username,</p>
                    <p class="text">Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>
                    <p class="text">Вскоре мы свяжемся с Вами</p>
                    <div class="btn-white header-call--success__close"><span class="text">Закрыть</span></div>
                </div>
```

нужно будет заменить в этом теге на текст, который пользователи вводит в поле "имя"

```
<p class="name">Username,</p>
```

Comment: Так а в чём проблема? В случае успеха(`succes:`) пишите туда значение `input[name="name"]` и все дела.

Comment: `$('.header__call-form--success > .name').text(formData.get('name'));`

Comment: получилось) отлично, примерно так и представлял, но пока в синтаксисе не разобрался. Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, это ответом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("form#dataler").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'sendler.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: formData,
    success: function success(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('.header__call-form').hide();
      $('.header__call-form--success').show();
      $('.header__call-form--success > .name').text(formData.get('name')+', ');
    },
    error: function error(data) {
      console.log('error');
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="job-form header__call-form" id="dataler" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="checked_form" value="Заказ обратного звонка">
  <div class="title">
    <p>Заказ обратного звонка</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
      <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder=" " required name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
      <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder=" " required name="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <fieldset class="header__call-quest">
        <legend>Когда вам перезвонить?</legend>
        <label>
<input id="timeChoice1" type="radio" name="worktime[]" checked value="Сейчас"><span>Сейчас</span>
</label>
        <label>
<input id="timeChoice2" type="radio" name="worktime[]" value="Вечером"><span>Вечером</span>
</label>
        <label>
<input id="timeChoice3" type="radio" name="worktime[]" value="Указать точное время"><span>Указать точное время</span>
</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="note">
      <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p><a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Заказать</span></button>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="header__call-form--success">
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="text">Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>
  <p class="text">Вскоре мы свяжемся с Вами</p>
  <div class="btn-white header-call--success__close"><span class="text">Закрыть</span></div>
</div>
```